# figure with subfloats is positioned incorrectly

Tags: floats, subfloats, ieeetran

I'm trying to position 3 figures in a column using this code (IEEE document):

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}

Text
\begin{figure}
\centering
\makebox[\columnwidth]{\subfloat[]{\label{Fig:fig1}\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{figures/fig1.eps}}}
\makebox[\columnwidth]{\subfloat[]{\label{Fig:fig2} \includegraphics[scale=0.6]{figures/fig2.eps}}}
\makebox[\columnwidth]{\subfloat[]{\label{Fig:fig3} \includegraphics[scale=0.6]{figures/fig3.eps}}}
\caption{caption}

\end{figure}

Text

\end{document}
```

I get the following result:

[image]

How can I center correctly the figures horizontal and vertical relatively ?

Thank you

Comment: Did you try `\linewidh`  instead of `\columnwidth`?

Comment: Yes, it didn't help

Comment: A minimal (non)working example would help.

Comment: I changed the code to full working example.

Comment: If that example really works for you, something is very odd about your set up. I know without even testing I'd get a compilation failure. Did you check it works before posting?

Comment: It worked fine for me as soon as I loaded  the `subfig` package. I had problems first on using `graphics` instead of `graphicx`.

Comment: If I add `subfig` and `\begin{document}`, it works fine for me. I get [this result](http://i.stack.imgur.com/cJ9G7.png).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your MWE are missing package `subfig` and `begin{document}` ... Also the use of `\makebox` is tu align figures in one column is not necesary. Try:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
    \begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
\subfloat[\label{Fig:fig1}]{\includegraphics[width=0.6\hsize]{figures/fig1.eps}}\\
\subfloat[\label{Fig:fig2}]{\includegraphics[width=0.6\hsize]{figures/fig2.eps}}\\
\subfloat[\label{Fig:fig3}]{\includegraphics[width=0.6\hsize]{figures/fig3.eps}}
    \caption{caption}
    \end{figure}

\lipsum[2-5]
    \end{document}
```

if this what you looking for: 
[image]

**Edit:**
It seems that problem of centering lie in width of real pictures, probably they are wider then column width. Their width can be limited with use of option `width` instead `scale` in `\includegraphics` macro as I change my MWE.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for. This works with the sample code but not in the required document

Comment: @Daniel, then you must investigated, (i) where preamble of my MWE differ from your document, and (ii) if my MWE work with yours pictures. One way, that you can discover what is wrong in your document, is adding missing packages to my MWE one by one and see, when the result as it is shown in my answer, disappear.

Comment: It does work with the demo pictures, it seems not to work with mine pictures.

Comment: @Daniel, what king is your pictures? are pictures wider then column width? If it is so, than the use of option`scale` is not right way to solve your proble, Tray tu use `width=\linewidth` ..., I edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: Problem solved, the issue was that figures were in EPS format and Latex was compiling to PDF. Changing to \hsize instead of scaling made it much better. Thanks